# Why can/should I include "undifferenced " variables in a first difference estimation?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

I am reading [this paper](https://www.nber.org/papers/w14312.pdf) and try to use their first-difference approach in a similar setting. They are essentially estimating the following first-difference specification, where Yit is Patenting, Xit is the independent variable of interest (immigration), µt are time fixed effects and Zit and Wit is a set of control variables: 
[image]

My question is why can I or even should I include "undifferenced" controls (Wit) and under what conditions can I do so.

Thank you in advance for any answers! Any explanations, insights or literature suggestions on first-difference estimations are highly appreciated!

Comment: Well, if there is a external regressors that can have an effect the difference between observations at time $t$ and $t+1$, you should definitely include that in your model. Pay attention to the fact that it could (and will most often) be its value (rather than its difference) what causes the difference in the output

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it useful to explicitly write out a theoretical model for the outcome (not the first difference of the outcome) and see what effect that taking the first difference has. I will use a simpler model than the one in your question, to illustrate my point.

Suppose that $$Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it} + \beta_2 U_i + \beta_3 t + \varepsilon_{it}, \tag{1}$$
where $U_i$ is an unobserved variable that varies between individuals but not over time (e.g. country of origin), $t$ is a measurement of time (e.g. years since the start of the study) and $\varepsilon_{it}$ is a random error term. Since $U_i$ isn't observed, $\beta_1$ is not identified by regressing $Y_{it}$ on $X_{it}$. This is the classic omitted variable bias problem.

However, by taking the first difference of $(1)$ we obtain: $$Y_{it}-Y_{it-1} = \\ \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it} + \beta_2 U_i + \beta_3 t  + \varepsilon_{it} - \left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it-1} + \beta_2 U_i + \beta_3 (t-1) + \varepsilon_{it-1}\right) \\ = \beta_3 + \beta_1(X_{it}-X_{it-1})\tag{2} + \varepsilon_{it}^*$$ 
We can thus see that we can identify $\beta_1$ by regressing $\Delta Y_{it}$ on $\Delta X_{it}$, where $\Delta$ is the first difference operator. This is a reason why first difference models are used; they let us estimate $\beta_1$ in the presence of unobserved (but time invariant) variables.

From this point of view, the question of including a variable $W_{it}$ in the right hand side of a FD model, is if we can specify a specification for $Y_{it}$ where it leads to the variable appearing as $W_{it}$ (as opposed to $\Delta W_{it}$) after taking the difference. It is not clear to me how such a specification would be done, so I would be very skeptical of including a *time-varying* variable without taking the first difference.

Note however the emphasis on *time-varying* in that previous sentence. Because let's consider a variable $V_i$ that varies between individuals but not over time. Furthermore, let's assume that the effect $V_i$ has on the outcome varies with time, i.e. that despite $V_i$ being constant over time, it's effect on $Y_{it}$ is not. This can be expressed, after some algebra, as follows:

$$Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it} + \beta_2 U_i + \beta_3 t + \beta_4 V_i + \beta_5 V_it + \varepsilon_{it}, \tag{3}$$
Note the addition of the interaction term between $V_i$ and $t$ in (3).

Taking the first difference of $(3)$ we end up with 
$$\Delta Y_{it} = \beta_3 + \beta_1 \Delta X_{it} + \beta_5 V_i + \varepsilon_{it}^*, \tag{4}$$

The reason why $V_i$ remains after taking the first difference is due to $\beta_5V_i t - \beta_5 V_i (t-1) = \beta_5 V_i t - \beta_5 V_i t + \beta_5 V_i = \beta_5 V_i$

This means that if we have a linear trend, we can estimate the interaction effect of time and time-invariant variables.

Looking at equation $(10)$ on page 9 of the article you linked to, they have included $Z_{i, 1950}$ in the right-hand side. There, $Z_{i, 1950}$ "are  characteristics of the state in 1950", which by definition is time-invariant. So if that is the equation that you were referring to in your question, they have not kept a time-varying variable in the model without taking the first difference. (Disclaimer: I have not read the article you linked to, just glanced at a few formulas.)

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! You kept me from making a serious error in my estimations. Your answer was of great help!